# Xubuntu/xfce stack tabs on panel

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I am using Xubuntu 16.04.

I am wondering if there is a way to have multiple opened instances of the same application stack into a single tab like Windows does it.

Then when you clickthat tab, it is expanded into a small secondary menu display all of the instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right-Click on your panel and select *Panel > Panel Preferences*.

Click on the Items tab and select `Windows Buttons`.

[image]

Click on the Gear on the right for `Edit the currently selected item` (my icon pack shows it as an eye ball).  Change `Window Grouping` to `Always`.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me to ungroup the instances.